# Rails, Fetching specific screen's data from Google Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I have Google Analytics which tracks specific Screens from my Android applicaiton. Lets say it called `News`. Now I want to fetch data to my rails applicaiton. I use `google-api-client`.

In my Google Developer console I have downloaded `client_secret.json` file. My Google Developer and Google Analytics use same account.

I have placed this JSON file to `config` folder and call it this way:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(
    application_name: 'App Name',
    application_version: 1
)
client.authorization =
    Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(
        File.join(
            Rails.root,
            'config',
            'client_secret.json'
        )
    ).to_authorization
```

Then... then... I don't know what to do.

How to get data from specific screens? How to sort them by my custom dimensions?

There is no proper documentation of how to use this API. Google just [says how to install it](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/analytics/v3) and ruby-docs **cannot find documentation of this gem**. Most tutorials are outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - this is documentation for Ruby API client. And you need to check API documentation (not client specific) to see how to use it (with whatever client).

So check out the [API documentation for Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/)

Comment: I will check your answer sooner.